# If every countable subset of a set $X$ is finite, does this imply that $X$ is finite?

Tags: set-theory

This claim seems intuitively true to me, but I'm having trouble coming up with a rigorous proof. My first idea was to construct two subsets whose union is the entire set, but I'm having trouble proving that two such subsets must exist.

It could be true that this claim is false, but so far I haven't been able to find any counterexamples.

Comment: If X is infinite, it contains a copy of the natural numbers, but this needs the axiom of choice. Are you admitting that?

Comment: I suspect that the axiom of choice will help you show that any infinite set $X$ has a countably infinite subset.  Just choose an element of $X$, then another, and so on

Comment: You need the axiom of choice for this. Without the axiom of choice, there can exist not finite sets all of whose subsets are finite or cofinite.

Comment: Btw, a set whose countable subsets are all finite is commonly called a Dedekind-finite set.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! I learned a lot about set theory that I didn't know before. It's surprising to me that something that seems so intuitive can't just be proven in ZF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mention, it depends on which axioms of set theory are being used. Without a sufficiently strong form of Choice Principle, it need not be true. In particular, if we assume that every infinite set has a countably-infinite subset (that is, that every infinite set is [Dedekind-infinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Dedekind-infinite_sets_in_ZF)), then it is immediately true. However, if our set theory allows for [infinite, Dedekind-finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Relation_to_the_axiom_of_choice) (infinite sets without any countably-infinite subsets), then such sets will have the property of being infinite, while all of their countable subsets are finite.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!